# How can I check for each and every module or set of files size in my .ipa file?

Tags: ios, xcode, optimization, xcode7, ipa

we have implemented one universal application. It's a huge application and 6-8 SDKs are integrated, So the entire app is taking around 40MB size.

After all, we want to reduce the size of the application. So we started the investigation, where exactly it is taking more size. What I know is, I can check for useless view controllers, and I can remove 1x images. And these things we can do in Xcode. But what if we want to know the sizes it is taking in .ipa file itself. Is it possible ?

But is there any better way to know the .ipa size module/ SDK wise. Please let me know. Any optimisation tool are available ?

Answer (score 0):

The following post has good advice on optimizations
https://medium.com/@mandrigin/ios-app-performance-instruments-beyond-48fe7b7cdf2#.btdp7bv5t

Also, you can try to access images in the IPA file using such tools like iBrowse and even better if you have a device with a firmware less than 9.3.3 to perform a jailbreak and investigate.

You can go even deeper by:

- reducing image size using tools like imageAlpha & imageOptim which are both free
- take a look at webP image format developed by google
  https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/#webp_support_stylefont-weight_bold

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to know the size before optimising my code. And I wanted to calculate each SDK size from the .ipa file. Is it possible ?

Comment: The IPA file is just an archive file and you can investigate how much memory each SDK , each resource takes.
Hope the following link will be helpful
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1795/_index.html